# Java reading data from a .txt file and outputting it to an output.txt file

Tags: java

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class ProgramSix {

    public int count(String fileName, char charToSerach) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        char lower = Character.toLowerCase(charToSerach);
        char upper = Character.toUpperCase(charToSerach);

        int count = 0;

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"))) {
            int ch = 0;
            while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
                if (lower == ch || upper == ch) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The character '" + charToSerach + "' appears: " + count + " times in the .txt file");
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Program6 program6 = new Program6();

            String fileName = "xanadu";
            int numAs = programSix.count(fileName, 'a');
            int numBs = programSix.count(fileName, 'b');
            int numCs = programSix.count(fileName, 'c');

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So now my code properly gives the output: giving the number of times the characters 'a' 'b' and 'c' appeared in my .txt file. Now what is the best way to read the same .txt file and give out three different letters in a output.txt file and the number of times they occurred?

Comment: What you get as output ?

Comment: does the file even exist?

Comment: Maybe an exception is happening...but you could answer this question yourself by adding a breakpoint to your code and _debugging_ it.

Comment: @User4392892 the output it gives is just a on the first line, b on the second line and thats it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im sorry how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Yeah the file does exist

Comment: why would you pass in the filename **and** hard-code it?

Comment: Okay I just changed around the code a bit, and now it gives the output of every 'a' or 'A' that appeared in my .txt file

Comment: Your program won't even compile - `Program6` != `ProgramSix`

Comment: Thanks everyone I resolved this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong class

see

```
class  ProgramSix
```

vs

```
Program6 program6 = new Program6();
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you. But will this make difference in the output?

Comment: If this code compiles then at some stage you must have had a class called `Program6` - it is not the above code

Comment: I changed them and got the correct output, thank you for recognizing my dumb mistake

Comment: That's great, please upvote and/or accept my answer

Comment: Will do I gotta wait like six minutes first tho, I also have another part to my question that I need to add maybe you can take a look at it

Comment: I just updated my post if you can take a look at it again. Thank you

Comment: what is wrong with the way that you are doing it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way I am doing it, its just its an assignment and I need to also output the same answer to an output.txt file if you know how to do that

Comment: try spending a couple of seconds to search for it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java

Comment: I have added the code that they suggested I am not sure what to put in my .out.println() that gives the output to the .txt file. Like I am not just posting the letters I need it to read my .txt file

Comment: why don't you open a new question - if you have one

Comment: I would but I'm pretty sure I won't be able to because everyone down rated this and put my question on hold.